# How to run a schedule job in a AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-batch

In my application, I need to run a fargate job(Job1) which loops through a particular task and invokes multiple tasks of fargate Job(Job2). So I want to know what are the possible ways to run this whole operation as a scheduled task? I tried to create ECS cluster with 2 containers and schedule both job1, and job2 using cloud watch events to run. But i was wondering what is the use of AWS Batch? Was is it an alternative for Cloud watch events? Suggest your thoughts please

Answer (score 2):

You could use [AWS EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/index.html) for this task, it uses the same underlying API as CloudWatch Events but with some relevant architectural changes to better implement an event-driven architecture.

[Here's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html) the official documentation how to implement a schedule rule, you're looking to use a ECS [Target](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-targets.html)

AWS Batch serves a different purpose than the one from your use case, as per their official documentation:

> AWS Batch enables developers, scientists, and engineers to easily and efficiently run hundreds of thousands of batch computing jobs on AWS. AWS Batch dynamically provisions the optimal quantity and type of compute resources (e.g., CPU or memory optimized instances) based on the volume and specific resource requirements of the batch jobs submitted.

What you're trying to do is quite simple, I recommend you keep it simple and don't try to overcomplicate it.